# Problem re-assembling front cover clips on an iMac 5,1

Tags: imac, hardware

I had to pull my iMac apart in order to extract a CD from the drive.  I have it all back together now except for getting the front cover on.  I am being defeated by the clips at the top inside of the cover.

I have looked online and all I can find are instructions on how to *disassemble* my iMac (which includes shoving a credit card up the airflow slot at the back of the iMac in order to release the clips).  The only advice I have seen about re-assembling is basically

> follow the disassembly steps in reverse order

But this isn't working for me for these clips.  Is there some secret/trick to clicking these clips into place when re-assembling an iMac 5,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacing the Front Bezel (17-inch)

1. Position the front bezel near the top edge of the unit and connect the two camera board connectors.
2. Make sure the black EMI shielding along the top of the LCD panel is not in the way of the locking mechanisms when you lower the front bezel onto the computer. Use a black stick to press (re-stick) the EMI shielding along the top of the panel.

   [image]
3. Wrap the cables with kapton tape then tuck the cables neatly into the channel on the rear housing.

   [image]
4. Make sure the memory ejector levers are in the closed position (as shown) before lowering the front bezel over the ejectors.

   [image]
5. Continue to lower the font bezel down and press the top corners of the front bezel to connect the latches. Note: Check that the latches are connected by lifting the front bezel at each corner.
6. Replace the four bezel screws along the bottom of the computer.
7. Replace the access door and tighten the two captive screws.
8. Install any removed DIMMS after the unit is fully assembled. Important: Memory DIMMs must be installed by hand. Do not use the memory ejector levers to install memory.

### Replacing the Front Bezel (20-inch)

1. Make sure the black EMI shielding along the top of the LCD panel is not in the way of the locking mechanisms when you lower the front bezel onto the computer. Use a black stick to press (re-stick) the EMI shielding along the top of the panel.

   [image]
2. Connect the camera and microphone cables (on the camera board) to the cables sticking out of the top of the computer.

   [image]
3. Tuck the cables neatly into the channel on the rear housing.

   [image]
4. Press the memory ejector levers into the closed position.
5. Continue to lower the font bezel down and press the top corners of the front bezel to connect the latches. Note: Check that the latches are connected by lifting the front bezel at each corner.
6. Replace the four bezel mounting screws along the bottom of the computer.
7. Replace the access door; tighten the two captive screws.

### References

[Service Source, iMac (17-inch Late 2006), 29 October 2007, Apple Inc., pp. 31-32](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/imac/imac_17_late_06.pdf)
[Service Source, iMac (20-inch Late 2006), 13 December 2007, Apple Inc., pp. 27-28](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/imac/imac_20_late_06.pdf)

Comment: The dis-assembling instructions I had seen start with releasing the latches at the top and pulling the top of the bezel out first and then the bottom. To me, reversing the order implies putting the bottom in first and then finally the top.  What you are showing is the opposite - top in first and then bottom.  That make a lot more sense.  Thanks.